# Graphical TOC Entry for J. Phys. Chem. Lett. (using achemso)

Tags: table-of-contents, achemso

Using `achemso`, how can I correctly insert the image of a Graphical TOC entry? Also, how can I specify the size of the image?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can use `\includegrapics` as normal.

Comment: %Example
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\begin{tocentry}
%\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=4.5cm]{graphical_TOC.jpg}
%\end{tocentry}
 This example procuces a crash. It seems that the size of the image is not properly set.